# client side events for html textbox and html button is not triggered on bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have called textbox onchange event and button click event. the textbox and htmlbutton in bootstrap Modal body. these events are not triggered.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
                 $('#mybutton').on('click', function (evt) {
                alert("htmlbutton clik");
            });
            $("#input1").change(function () {
                alert("htmltext changed");
            });
         });
</script>
<div class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          <input type="button" id="mybutton" value="htmlbutton" />
          <input type="text" id="input1" value="htmltext" />
  </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
```

Comment: Your code looks fine.. Additional information needed.. Are you creating those html elements dynamically.?

Comment: yes i have add the above code in partial view,  and call the bootstrap modal in main page as:var url = $(this).attr("href") + "?" + dateTime.getMilliseconds();
             $.get(url, function (htmlData) {
                 $(htmlData).modal();
             });

Answer (score 0):

Your Code looks fine. Not sure if you included Jquery here is the complete code

```
<html>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
                 $('#mybutton').on('click', function (evt) {
                alert("htmlbutton clik");
            });

         });
</script>
<div class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          <input type="button" id="mybutton" value="htmlbutton" />
          <input type="text" id="input1" value="htmltext" />
  </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<script>
 $("#input1").on('change',function () {
                alert("htmltext changed");
            });
$("#input1").on('keypress',function () {
alert("htmltext changed");
});

</script>
</html>
```

Did the key press part seperatly for better understanding of the code.

Comment: only jquery 1.11 supports bootstrap modal events?

Comment: It can support on any JQUERy. If working choose it as correct answer so that it would be useful for others.